# Best travel path from Buenos Aires to Aysen Region, Chile

Tags: chile, patagonia

I want to travel from Buenos Aires, Argentina to the Aysen Region in Chile, preferably to [Cochrane Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochrane_Airfield) (LGR).

Are there charter airlines going to that or the other airports nearby?

Most routes go via Balmaceda (BBA) and then 300km by car.

Comment: This is a rather large area.  You want to narrow it down to a town or 2?

Comment: Preferably to Cochrane (Airport (LGR))

Comment: Best in what way?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to Cochrane you will need to charter a flight at Coyhaique.  You can look at [Lonely Planet article](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/chile/northern-patagonia/coyhaique/transport/getting-there-away/flights).

I can't find any charters online that actually do flights to Cochrane.  The only one mentioned was a Helicopter charter company [Discovery Air](http://www.discoveryair.cl).